# Search guard LDAP authentication - Authentication finally failed for user - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ldap

I'm trying to set LDAP Elasticsearch authentication using cannonical name (cn)

I’m searching Default User OU with Domain Admin credentials (as a test), i created user user1 and put him in Administrators group (same group as Domain admin) and using cn as user name

cn=user1

samaccountname=user1

sg_roles.yml:

```
ldap:
    http_enabled: false
    transport_enabled: false
    order: 5
    http_authenticator:
      type: basic
      challenge: false
    authentication_backend:
      # LDAP authentication backend (authenticate users against a LDAP or Active Directory)
      type: ldap # NOT FREE FOR COMMERCIAL USE
      config:
        # enable ldaps
        enable_ssl: false
        # enable start tls, enable_ssl should be false
        enable_start_tls: false
        # send client certificate
        enable_ssl_client_auth: false
        # verify ldap hostname
        verify_hostnames: true
        hosts:
          - dc.test.com:389
        bind_dn: cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com
        password: Pass
        userbase: 'cn=Administrators,cn=Builtin,dc=test,dc=com'
        # Filter to search for users (currently in the whole subtree beneath userbase)
        # {0} is substituted with the username
        usersearch: '(sAMAccountName={0})'
        # Use this attribute from the user as username (if not set then DN is used)
        username_attribute: cn
authz:
  roles_from_myldap:
    http_enabled: false
    transport_enabled: false
    authorization_backend:
      # LDAP authorization backend (gather roles from a LDAP or Active Directory, you have to configure the above LDAP authentication backend settings too)
      type: ldap # NOT FREE FOR COMMERCIAL USE
      config:
        # enable ldaps
        enable_ssl: false
        # enable start tls, enable_ssl should be false
        enable_start_tls: false
        # send client certificate
        enable_ssl_client_auth: false
        # verify ldap hostname
        verify_hostnames: true
        hosts:
          - dc.test.com:389
        bind_dn: cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com
        password: Pass
        rolebase: 'cn=Builtin,dc=test,dc=com'
        # Filter to search for roles (currently in the whole subtree beneath rolebase)
        # {0} is substituted with the DN of the user
        # {1} is substituted with the username
        # {2} is substituted with an attribute value from user's directory entry, of the authenticated user. Use userroleattribute to specify the name of the attribute
        rolesearch: '(member={0})'
        # Specify the name of the attribute which value should be substituted with {2} above
        userroleattribute: null
        # Roles as an attribute of the user entry
        #userrolename: disabled
        userrolename: memberOf
        # The attribute in a role entry containing the name of that role, Default is "name".
        # Can also be "dn" to use the full DN as rolename.
        rolename: cn
        # Resolve nested roles transitive (roles which are members of other roles and so on ...)
        resolve_nested_roles: true
        userbase: 'cn=Administrators,cn=Builtin,dc=test,dc=com'
        # Filter to search for users (currently in the whole subtree beneath userbase)
        # {0} is substituted with the username
        usersearch: '(uid={0})'
        # Skip users matching a user name, a wildcard or a regex pattern
        #skip_users:
        #  - 'cn=Michael Jackson,ou*people,o=TEST'
        #  - '/\S*/'
  roles_from_another_ldap:
    enabled: false
```

sg_roles.yml

```
sg_ad_admins:
  readonly: true
  cluster:
    - UNLIMITED
  indices:
    '*':
      '*':
        - UNLIMITED
  tenants:
    admin_tenant: RW
```

sg_roles_mapping.yml

```
sg_ad_admins:
  backendroles:
    - "cn=Administrators,cn=Builtin,dc=test,dc=com"
```

when authenticatin with

```
curl -Ss -k https://user1:Pass@ekl.test.com:9200/_cluster/health
```

Getting

> [WARN ][c.f.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [1XeQ7xr] Authentication finally failed for >user1 from 172.17.252.71:51680
>   [2019-04-02T00:39:20,601][WARN ][c.f.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [1XeQ7xr] >Authentication finally failed for user1 from 172.17.252.71:51682
>   [2019-04-02T00:48:24,049][WARN ][c.f.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [1XeQ7xr] >Authentication finally failed for user1 from 172.17.252.71:51684
>   [root@vm1 sgconfig]#

Domain controller accessible from Elasticsearch on port 389

Authentication also fails for Administrator with same error.

**EDIT**

[image]

Recreated scenario

In test group is user1 which needs to authenticate to Easticsearch
in service_account OU is service account which searches AD for users.

User1:

```
CN=user1,OU=UA,DC=test,DC=com
```

In UA OU is user1 (member of test security group)

```
 ldap:
        http_enabled: true
        transport_enabled: true
        order: 2
        http_authenticator:
          type: basic
          challenge: false
        authentication_backend:
          # LDAP authentication backend (authenticate users against a LDAP or Active Directory)
          type: ldap # NOT FREE FOR COMMERCIAL USE
          config:
            # enable ldaps
            enable_ssl: false
            # enable start tls, enable_ssl should be false
            enable_start_tls: false
            # send client certificate
            enable_ssl_client_auth: false
            # verify ldap hostname
            verify_hostnames: true
            hosts:
              - dc.test.com:389
            bind_dn: "CN=service,OU=service_accounts,DC=test,DC=com"
            password: "Pass"
            userbase: "OU=UA,DC=test,DC=com"
            # Filter to search for users (currently in the whole subtree beneath userbase)
            # {0} is substituted with the username
            usersearch: "(cn={0})"
            # Use this attribute from the user as username (if not set then DN is used)
            username_attribute: "cn"
    authz:
      roles_from_myldap:
        http_enabled: false
        transport_enabled: false
        authorization_backend:
          # LDAP authorization backend (gather roles from a LDAP or Active Directory, you have to configure the above LDAP authentication backend settings too)
          type: ldap # NOT FREE FOR COMMERCIAL USE
          config:
            # enable ldaps
            enable_ssl: false
            # enable start tls, enable_ssl should be false
            enable_start_tls: false
            # send client certificate
            enable_ssl_client_auth: false
            # verify ldap hostname
            verify_hostnames: true
            hosts:
              - "dc.test.com:389"
            bind_dn: "CN=service,OU=service_accounts,DC=test,DC=com"
            password: "Pass"
            #rolebase: "OU=UA,DC=test,DC=com"
            rolebase: "CN=test,OU=groups,DC=test,DC=com"
            # Filter to search for roles (currently in the whole subtree beneath rolebase)
            # {0} is substituted with the DN of the user
            # {1} is substituted with the username
            # {2} is substituted with an attribute value from user's directory entry, of the authenticated user. Use userroleattribute to specify the name of the attribute
            rolesearch: "(member={0})"
            # Specify the name of the attribute which value should be substituted with {2} above
            userroleattribute: null
            # Roles as an attribute of the user entry
            #userrolename: disabled
            userrolename: "memberOf"
            # The attribute in a role entry containing the name of that role, Default is "name".
            # Can also be "dn" to use the full DN as rolename.
            rolename: "cn"
            # Resolve nested roles transitive (roles which are members of other roles and so on ...)
            resolve_nested_roles: "true"
            userbase: 'CN=test,OU=groups,DC=test,DC=com'
            # Filter to search for users (currently in the whole subtree beneath userbase)
            # {0} is substituted with the username
            usersearch: "(cn={0})"
            # Skip users matching a user name, a wildcard or a regex pattern
            #skip_users:
            #  - 'cn=Michael Jackson,ou*people,o=TEST'
            #  - '/\S*/'
      roles_from_another_ldap:
        enabled: false
        authorization_backend:
```

Now, i can authenticate but role is not mapped

```
curl -Ss -k https://user1:Pass@ekl.test.com:9200/_cluster/health
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"no permissions for [cluster:monitor/health] and User [name=user1, roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"no permissions for [cluster:monitor/health] and User [name=user1, roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"},"status":403}
```

Comment: Whats the DN of the `user1` you created? The `userbase` might not be correct. You can also increase the log level for SearchGuard following these instructions https://docs.search-guard.com/latest/troubleshooting-setting-log-level

Comment: just updated question

Comment: It's now not finding the roles for your user. The `rolebase` looks incorrect, try with `OU=groups,DC=test,DC=com`

Comment: already did it, bit same issue

Comment: If you update your question to show the most recent version of your config, and the attributes of the test group in Active directory that would be helpful. You could also try commenting out `userrolename` as the docs indicate that field is the field on the user that you wish to get the groups from (which is not the case in your config)

Comment: just figured it out and posted solution, had to change to `http_enabled: true
transport_enabled: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working, Search Guard documentation is terrible:

```
ldap:
        http_enabled: true
        transport_enabled: true
        order: 2
        http_authenticator:
          type: basic
          challenge: false
        authentication_backend:
          # LDAP authentication backend (authenticate users against a LDAP or Active Directory)
          type: ldap # NOT FREE FOR COMMERCIAL USE
          config:
            # enable ldaps
            enable_ssl: false
            # enable start tls, enable_ssl should be false
            enable_start_tls: false
            # send client certificate
            enable_ssl_client_auth: false
            # verify ldap hostname
            verify_hostnames: true
            hosts:
              - dc.test.com:389
            bind_dn: "CN=service,OU=service_accounts,DC=test,DC=com"
            password: "Pass"
            userbase: "OU=UA,DC=test,DC=com"
            # Filter to search for users (currently in the whole subtree beneath userbase)
            # {0} is substituted with the username
            usersearch: "(cn={0})"
            # Use this attribute from the user as username (if not set then DN is used)
            username_attribute: "cn"
    authz:
      roles_from_myldap:
        http_enabled: true
        transport_enabled: true
        authorization_backend:
          # LDAP authorization backend (gather roles from a LDAP or Active Directory, you have to configure the above LDAP authentication backend settings too)
          type: ldap # NOT FREE FOR COMMERCIAL USE
          config:
            # enable ldaps
            enable_ssl: false
            # enable start tls, enable_ssl should be false
            enable_start_tls: false
            # send client certificate
            enable_ssl_client_auth: false
            # verify ldap hostname
            verify_hostnames: true
            hosts:
              - "dc.test.com:389"
            bind_dn: "CN=service,OU=service_accounts,DC=test,DC=com"
            password: "Pass"
            #rolebase: "OU=UA,DC=test,DC=com"
            rolebase: "CN=test,OU=groups,DC=test,DC=com"
            # Filter to search for roles (currently in the whole subtree beneath rolebase)
            # {0} is substituted with the DN of the user
            # {1} is substituted with the username
            # {2} is substituted with an attribute value from user's directory entry, of the authenticated user. Use userroleattribute to specify the name of the attribute
            rolesearch: "(member={0})"
            # Specify the name of the attribute which value should be substituted with {2} above
            userroleattribute: null
            # Roles as an attribute of the user entry
            #userrolename: disabled
            userrolename: "memberOf"
            # The attribute in a role entry containing the name of that role, Default is "name".
            # Can also be "dn" to use the full DN as rolename.
            rolename: "cn"
            # Resolve nested roles transitive (roles which are members of other roles and so on ...)
            resolve_nested_roles: "true"
            userbase: 'CN=test,OU=groups,DC=test,DC=com'
            # Filter to search for users (currently in the whole subtree beneath userbase)
            # {0} is substituted with the username
            usersearch: "(cn={0})"
            # Skip users matching a user name, a wildcard or a regex pattern
            #skip_users:
            #  - 'cn=Michael Jackson,ou*people,o=TEST'
            #  - '/\S*/'
      roles_from_another_ldap:
        enabled: false
        authorization_backend:
```

and had to change sg_roles_mapping.yml"

sg_ad_admin:

```
  readonly: true
  backendroles:
    - test
```